# How to slide the images using jquery?

Tags: jquery

I hav a few images. I want to slide them one after the another using jquery. Pls help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/scrollable/vertical.html

Some more info -

```
//vertical is the class of parent container
.vertical {
    border-top:1px solid #DDDDDD;
    height:665px; // just increase it for showing more images.
    overflow:hidden; //causing images to hide.
    position:relative;
    width:700px;
 }
```

[Working Example showing just two images](http://www.jsfiddle.net/Y9fVn/)

[Working Example showing four images](http://www.jsfiddle.net/Y9fVn/1/)